# Is stud bolts covered under ASME B18.2.1

Tags: mechanical-engineering, piping

I want to know if stud bolt dimensions are covered under ASME B18.2.1. I could not specifically find them in the standard or they may be included under some other technical name within the same standard or covered in a different standard. I am a newbie. Hence the doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stud bolt dimensions are covered under several standards.

The stud bolt lengths are defined in the ASME B16.5 standard.

Bolts' threadings are defined in ASME B1.1 Unified Inch Screw Threads, (UN and UNR Thread Form).

There are several standards covering the material and other properties.

[image: stud bollts and hex bolts]

This article is helpful. [Bolts and nuts.](http://www.wermac.org/bolts/bolts_stud-bolts_for-flanged-connections.html)

Comment: Additionally, I found out that ASME B18.31.2 also covers flange studs [link](https://www.asme.org/codes-standards/find-codes-standards/b18-31-2-continuous-thread-stud-double-end-stud-flange-bolting-stud)